# Query exhausted resources on this scale factor

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to left join a very big table (52 MIllion rows) to a massive table with 11,553,668,111 observations, but just two columns

Simple left join commands err out with "Query exhausted resources at this scale factor."

```
-- create smaller table to save $$
CREATE TABLE targetsmart_idl_data_mi_pa_maid AS 
SELECT targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.idl,  targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.grouping_indicator, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.vb_voterbase_dob, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.vb_voterbase_gender, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.ts_tsmart_urbanicity, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.ts_tsmart_high_school_only_score,
targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.ts_tsmart_college_graduate_score, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.ts_tsmart_partisan_score, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.ts_tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.vb_voterbase_marital_status, targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.vb_tsmart_census_id, 
targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.vb_voterbase_deceased_flag,  idl_maid_base.maid
FROM targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa
LEFT JOIN idl_maid_base
    ON targetsmart_idl_data_pa_mi_pa.idl = idl_maid_base.idl
```

Comment: With 11 billion records, no wonder.

Comment: I am aware this is large, but is the answer simply that Athena can't handle data that large? I can partition it into two parts, but not much more than that

Comment: Please help us help you and expand your question with what you want us to help you with. Do you want to know how to get the query to run? Do you want confirmation that this is not going to work? What would a helpful answer look like to you?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome the issue by having the large table as driving table

For example.

```
select col1, col2 from table a join table b on a.col1 =b.col1
```

table a is small with less than 1000 records where as table b has millions of records. The above query error out

Re-write the query as

```
select col1, col2 from table b join table a on a.col1 =b.col1
```